# Ember2.8 : Refresh absolutely everything on transitionToRoute('/route')

Tags: ember.js

So I currently have a card game that when finished loads up a modal with a button to transition back to the home route. This is the action that is called when the modal's close button is clicked.

```
goBackHome() {
  this.transitionToRoute('/games');
},
```

It does redirect to the requested route, but all the changes to back-end data I did still remain. I've also tried passing it the model itself

```
goBackHome() {
  this.transitionToRoute('games');
},
```

Basically, it doesn't do a hard refresh of everything. What I would like is when transitionToRoute is called to reload the route as if I was inputting the exact URL into the browser myself.

Comment: You are not supposed to pass URLs to `transitionToRoute`, but the route name that you want to go to.

Comment: You can always manually set `window.location`. However I don't recommend this, this will trigger a full reload of the application. Maybe just call `.rollbackAttributes()` on your model?

Comment: @Lux This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I don't need to store any kind of changes to my models in the application, so this nifty trick worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Well I try to write possible way to do this, hope you can pick one and solve your problem.

you need to add  `this.refresh();` to either your method or in `model()` to force reload the model to get new data (depends on what you need)! if you want to reload the location the whole windows I mean just add `location.reload();`

one example should be

```
model(id){
    var post = this.get('store').find('post', id); // Find the post from the store
    post.reload(); // Force a reload
    return post;  // Return the fetched post NOW and the information will be updated.
  }
```

Moreover, you can do something else in your model() look at the example :

```
 model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('whatever', params.id, { reload: true });
  }
```

this `{ reload: true }` enforces the model to get fresh data, it can be implemented with `findAll` as well.

[ref:](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3704#issuecomment-200919707) At the moment I'm just using the afterModel hook to force a reload, but it would be good to get the reload flag working again.

so, you can do also another way which is you can send a param to the function and get that in route and in route `actions` you can have `this.referesh()`! to reload the model. In this case, you need to add `this.sendAction('actionName');`  and in route `actionName(){this.referesh();}`

Comment: "force the mode to be reloaded every single time" this isn't exactly what it does, and it doesn't matter if the `model()` hook is skipped.

Comment: @lokcs good point, thanks just altered. if you have more suggestions please feel free to edit my answer. thanks a lot.